# use jQuery setInterval to decreases the width of element but from only one side (left or right )

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

here are my codes for decreasing the width of an selected element(class = "life_bar"), but as my attached pictures show, I want it to decrease its width from left or right( let's do left as example), but it always goes from both side, what should I do? 
[image]
[image]
here are jQuery codes

```
$(function () {
    var timmer;
    gocount();
    function gocount(){
        timmer = setInterval(function () {
         var life_bar_width = $(".life_bar").width();
            life_bar_width -= 100;
            $(".life_bar").css( {width: life_bar_width,
                left: '-50px'})
        },1000);
    }
});
```

here are css codes

```
.life_bar{
    width: 500px;
    height: 10px;
    background: crimson;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
```

here are html codes

```
<body>
<div class="life_bar"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I guess you would have to move it left / right the amount of pixels you decrease it's width by

Comment: Or put it in a container that remains the same width as the bar starts

Comment: `margin: 100px 0;`

Answer (score 1):

using translate negative on X every interval tick:

```js
$(function () {
  var timmer;
  gocount();
  let counter = 1
  function gocount(){
    timmer = setInterval(function () {
     var life_bar_width = $(".life_bar").width();
      life_bar_width -= 100;
      $(".life_bar").css({
        width: life_bar_width,
        left: '-50px',
        transform: `translate(${-50*counter}px)`
      })
      counter++
    },1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.life_bar{
    width: 500px;
    height: 10px;
    background: crimson;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="life_bar"></div>
```